# emacs editor integrated on a browser

Tags: browser, emacs, editor, wysiwyg

I am doing some research but I cant find a tutorial or if it is possible. can I put emacs editor online, like any java script editors or wysiwyg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could embed a JavaScript SSH client and run Emacs on a real machine, but you're probably better off with [Ymacs](http://www.ymacs.org/) — it's an Emacs-like editor but Web-native.

Answer (score 3):

this firefox extension allows you to edit textareas with an external editor of your choice :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/